# How do you import Shared Libraries in groovysh?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, groovysh

Jenkins lets you import a shared library using:

```
library
```

But how would you do this using `groovysh`?

Comment: it's not clear what do you need or expect...

Answer (score 1):

Snowcrash.

I've been searching for a solution to the same issue. And have found a hint in [Jenkins Shared Library - Importing classes from the /src folder in /vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528285/jenkins-shared-library-importing-classes-from-the-src-folder-in-vars)

So, imagine, you have a directory tree `src/com/example/jenkins/class.groovy`. The launching command for groovy would be:

```
[library-root]$ groovysh -cp src
groovy:000> import com.example.jenkins.class
===> com.example.jenkins.class
groovy:000> new class('string')
===> com.example.jenkins.class@53a7a60c
```